# Evitar copias innecesarias

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo un objeto que internamente almacena una colección bastante pesada de objetos. Esta colección se rellena bajo demanda, es decir, si la colección no es necesaria no se va a rellenar en la vida:

```
class Objeto
{
  std::vector<int> coleccion;

  // Solo una factoría puede crear objetos de este tipo
  Objeto();

  void RellenarColeccion()
  { /* ... */ }

public:

  // No se admiten copias
  Objeto(Objeto const&) = delete;

  // Constructor move
  Objeto(Objeto &&) = default;

  std::vector<int> const& Coleccion()
  {
    if( coleccion.empty() )
      RellenarColeccion();

     return coleccion;
  }
};
```

La clase funciona perfectamente. Al devolver una referencia a la colección se evitan copias y el programa acaba funcionando razonablemente bien... hasta que surje la necesidad de copiar la colección del objeto.

Esta necesidad surje en una situación particular en la que lo único que interesa del objeto es su colección interna:

```
Objeto NuevoObjeto() // Función que emula la factoría
{ return Objeto; }

int main()
{
  // Se invoca la sintaxis move y la copia es bastante liviana
  Objeto o1 = NuevoObjeto();

  // Obtenemos la colección vía referencia. Evitamos la copia
  auto& v1 = o1.Coleccion();

  // El problema lo tenemos cuando del objeto solo queremos su coleccion
  // La copia es demasiado pesada
  auto v2 = NuevoObjeto().Coleccion();

  // Y no nos podemos quedar con la referencia
  auto& v3 = NuevoObjeto().Coleccion(); // Referencia a objeto destruido
}
```

¿Existe alguna solución que permita aprovechar la sintaxis *move* realizando cambios solo en `Objeto`? Lo esperable sería lo siguiente:

```
int main()
{
  // caso 1: se accede por referencia
  Objeto o1 = NuevoObjeto();
  auto& v1 = o1.Coleccion();

  // caso 2: Se llama a la sintaxis move para evitar la copia del vector
  auto v2 = NuevoObjeto().Coleccion();
}
```

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo bien, ¿lo que quieres es copiar el contenido de un objeto a otro usando las referencias?

Comment: @DanielGS echa un vistazo al último código. Lo que busco es una forma de evitar una copia al crear `v2`

Comment: Relacionado: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @SJuan76 relacionado con pinzas. Lo que hay en ese enlace no te va a dar la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible marcar una función miembro para que sea llamada cuando se aplica sobre un objeto temporal (u objeto de tipo valor-derecho), para ello se añade `&&` al final de la firma de la función, esto es conocido como "*cualificadores de referencia*" o "*referencia a valor-derecho para `*this`*", si usas estas funciones a tu `Objeto`:

```
std::vector<int> const& Coleccion() &
{
    if( coleccion.empty() )
        RellenarColeccion();

    return coleccion;
}

// Esta version de Coleccion sera llamada cuando el objeto sea un temporal
std::vector<int> Coleccion() &&
{
    if( coleccion.empty() )
        RellenarColeccion();

    return std::move(coleccion);
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- movemos la coleccion fuera del temporal
}
```

En la versión que usa una referencia a valor derecho para `*this`, usamos `std::move` para transformar la `coleccion` interna del objeto temporal en un vector valor-derecho, el cuál será usado para construir el `std::vector<int>` resultante que, al estar recibiendo un valor-derecho, moverá el contenido en lugar de copiarlo<sup>1</sup>. Para ver si esto funciona como necesitas, he hecho unos cambios en tu clase de ejemplo:

```
class Objeto
{
    using type_t = chivato;
    ::vector<type_t> coleccion;

    Objeto() { std::cout << this << ' ' << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

    friend Objeto NuevoObjeto(); // Otorgamos acceso a los miembros privados para la factoria

    void RellenarColeccion()
    { coleccion.emplace_back(); } // Anyadimos un objeto como prueba

public:
    ~Objeto() { std::cout << this << ' ' << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } // mostramos mensaje al destruir

    Objeto(Objeto const&) = delete;
    Objeto(Objeto &&) = default;

    std::vector<type_t> const& Coleccion() &
    {
        std::cout << "No temporal\n";
        if( coleccion.empty() )
            RellenarColeccion();

        return coleccion;
    }


    std::vector<type_t> Coleccion() &&
    {
        std::cout << "Temporal\n";
        if( coleccion.empty() )
            RellenarColeccion();

        return std::move(coleccion);
    }
};
```

He añadido unos mensajes en la construcción y destrucción de `Objeto` y cambiado el tipo del objeto contenido en la colección a este:

```
struct chivato
{
    chivato() { std::cout << this << ' ' << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    ~chivato() { std::cout << this << ' ' << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};
```

Con dichos cambios, si ejecutamos este código en `main`:

```
std::cout << "Objeto en main\n";
Objeto o1 = NuevoObjeto();
std::cout << "Referencia a coleccion\n";
auto& v1 = o1.Coleccion();

std::cout << "\nObjeto temporal del que se obtiene coleccion\n";
auto v2 = NuevoObjeto().Coleccion();
std::cout << "Despues\n";
```

Tenemos esta salida<sup>2</sup>:

> ```
> Objeto en main
> 0x000000000001 Objeto
> Referencia a coleccion
> No temporal
> 0x0000001 chivato
>
> Objeto temporal del que se obtiene coleccion
> 0x000000000002 Objeto
> Temporal
> 0x0000002 chivato
> 0x000000000002 ~Objeto
> Despues
> 0x0000002 ~chivato
> 0x000000000001 ~Objeto
> 0x0000001 ~chivato
> ```

Vemos que el primer `Objeto` (`0x000000000001`) crea una colección con el elemento `0x0000001` y se lee dicha colección mediante la función `Coleccion` que no se aplica sobre temporales, no vemos que el elemento `0x0000001` sea destruido.

En la segunda parte se crea un `Objeto` temporal (`0x000000000002`) que contiene el elemento `0x0000002` y acto seguido se destruye el `Objeto` sin que el elemento (`0x0000002`) sea destruido, eso significa que la colección ha sido movida, también podemos ver que se ha llamado la versión de `Coleccion` que se llama sobre temporales.

Después del mensaje `Después` se llaman los destructores del elemento de la colección del `Objeto` creado temporalmente desde la factoría (`0x0000002`), seguidamente se llama al destructor del primer `Objeto` (`0x000000000001`) creado el cuál llama al destructor de su único elemento (`0x0000001`).

Este comportamiento nos demuestra que no ha habido copia de la colección obtenida del temporal (de haber habido copia se vería una construcción-destrucción adicional de elementos de colección).

Puedes ver el código funcionando <kbd>[En **Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4eaPmRxbHNDqG0xG)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Atención, usar `std::move` en una instrucción `return` evita la [optimización del valor de retorno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

<sup>2</sup>He editado las direcciones de memoria, por claridad y porque en diferentes ejecuciones son diferentes valores.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, lo que tienes es lo siguiente:

```
  std::vector<int> const& Coleccion()
  {
    if( coleccion.empty() )
      RellenarColeccion();

     return coleccion;
  }
```

Como puedes ver, ahí retornas una lista, por lo que se hará una copia al crear v2. Lo que puedes hacer es retornar un puntero a esa colección, así simplemente estarás pasando una dirección en vez de toda una lista completa.

Podrías hacerlo retornando un `void *` y posteriormente haciendo un casting a tu std::vector:

```
int *coleccion = (int*)coleccion; //siendo coleccion lo que te ha retornado Coleccion()
std::vector<int > v(coleccion, coleccion+ len); //len es el tamaño de tu std::vector original
```

La modificación que propongo de tu método Coleccion() quedaría así:

```
  void * const& Coleccion()
  {
    if( coleccion.empty() )
      RellenarColeccion();

     return (void*)&coleccion[0];  //retornamos la dirección de la primera posición
  }
```

Así lo que haces es trabajar con referencias y no con copias de datos.
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Si siempre vas a trabajar con un `std::vector<int>` entonces puedes cambiar `void *` por `int *`

Comment: "*puedes cambiar `void *` por `int *`*" mejor no :) el C++ moderno se encamina al desuso de punteros en crudo, y más aún punteros sin tipo subyacente (como punteros a `void`) si los punteros fuesen una solución, serían en todo caso los punteros inteligentes no punteros en crudo.

Comment: Coincido con @PaperBirdMaster. Exponer punteros puede ser peligroso porque no sabes quien va a copiarse el puntero y el mismo puede acabar recibiendo un `delete`... La respuesta debería ser compatible con el `main` que cierra la pregunta sin hacerle cambios

Comment: Has caído en la trampa de estos dos pájaros; uno hace la pregunta cuando el otro ya preparó la respuesta.