# Constructor de movimiento en C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Estoy estudiando el constructor de movimiento en C++ que recibe una referencia a un valor-r del tipo de la clase.

El problema es que a pesar de ver varios libros de C++ Deitel y varios otros, **no encuentro absolutamente nada del constructor de movimiento**, solo tengo información en escasas diapositivas que no lo explican claramente.

¿Habría forma de que me ayudarás a saber cómo encontrar alguna información para aprender el constructor de movimiento en C++?

Ni siquiera en Google encuentro nada interesante para aprender dicho constructor.

Intentaré ser más concreto, veréis, sería sobre el constructor de movimiento en C++11. Es decir algo como:

```
class C
{
  public:
    C(C&& c) {...}
  //...
}
```

Sé que se llama implícitamente cuando un objeto se inicializa con una referencia a valor-r que es otro objeto de la misma clase.

Luego en lo "poco" que tengo de información, se expone una clase vector sin movimiento de objetos (con un constructor de copia, un destructor y un operador de asignación).

Y en el ejemplo me viene también un constructor de movimiento, asignación de movimiento y poco más, no sé si esto os sirve de ayuda para ayudarme.
Aquí os dejo con más información sobre el constructor que me da el ejemplo:

Constructor de movimiento:

```
Vector(Vector&& v);
```

Definición:

```
//Ctor de movimiento
Vector::Vector(Vector&& v): eltos{v.eltos}, n_eltos{v.n_eltos}
{
 v.eltos = nullptr; //Tras el movimiento se invoca
 v.n_eltos = 0; // al destructor de v.
}
```

Y otro más de asignación de movimiento:

```
Vector& Vector::operator= (Vector&& v) //Parametro no const
{
 delete[] eltos;
 eltos = v.eltos;
 n_eltos = v.n_eltos;
 v.eltos = nullptr; //Tras el movimiento se invocará
 v.n_eltos = 0; //al destructor de v
 return *this;
}
```

Comment: que entiendes tu por constructor de movimiento? a como manipula la memoria el compilador? o es alguna clase de objeto que se mueve en algún sitio?

Comment: @Trauma a ya, ese ese dolor de cabeza de manipular la dirección de memoria de los punteros... yo tengo un libro de eso!

Comment: Para que sea una pregunta como es debido, deberías añadir algunas pruebas sobre las que podamos trabajar. Mientras tanto, encontré [una charla en Español](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-g--AANs9FFUFkyTlRFZ2xfSE0/view?usp=sharing) que habla (entre otras cosas) del constructor de movimiento, revisa si te funciona el enlace.

Comment: https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.fbsbx.com%2Fv%2Ft59.2708-21%2F14690401_10154844246623646_2434834930245566464_n.pdf%2FEffective-Modern-C-2014.pdf%3Foh%3D3aadc0207b7e542952295442a4a74609%26oe%3D5A619DC2%26dl%3D1&h=ATMIDTIpbXsWWt0pVrITMKPwlMcLIYfCljA747P9lCsvtXuIg22rh3PMFkzDd_riGKBULdATm2pnQWFALRFuOWEboSHnRMHw4Ke6Vw0YN-DTYiP-f-h1LabgQldTv_0iCKDUxkzi7o4ZBgO1X3002b_cWB4&s=1&enc=AZMj-ls2pkacEXunC_UY5CdIj3eg7gZXQfPJi7wOasKRCAaUJ1pATsm2_vkRiayQ7Bo2qBlaBMwmasWlUb3eLY2rSrl01JPDnDhItrio889pQw

Comment: es un buen libro ojala sepas ingles

Comment: Buenas a todos, ya he actualizado la pregunta principal con más información, no obstante, seguiré pendiente al hilo para marcar la respuesta más aclaratoria. Gracias a todos

Comment: Pero exactamente ¿cuál es la pregunta? @ProgrammerJr

Comment: Puede servirte un artículo de msdn en: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd293665.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referencias previas:

- [¿Cuándo usar std::move y por qué?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/cu%C3%A1ndo-usar-stdmove-y-por-qu%C3%A9?s=1%7C52.4969)
- [Evitar copias innecesarias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98503/evitar-copias-innecesarias?s=5|22.0002)

**¿Qué es el constructor *move*?**

El constructor *move* vió la luz con el estándar C++11. Este constructor forma parte de lo que se conoce como *sintaxis move*, que se compone, a grandes rasgos, del constructor *move* y de un nuevo operador de asignación:

```
struct POO
{
  // Constructor move
  POO(POO&& obj)
  {
  }

  // Asignacion move
  POO& operator=(POO && obj)
  {
  }
};
```

**¿Cómo funciona?**

La `sintaxis move` tiene como objetivo evitar la copia innecesaria de grandes cantidades de información. Esto se consigue, básicamente, moviendo los punteros en vez de mover la información contenida en los mismos:

```
struct Objeto
{
  int numElems1;
  int* ptr1;

  int numElems2;
  char* ptr2;

  // Constructor por defecto
  Objeto()
  { /* ... */ }

  ~Objeto()
  {
    delete[] ptr1;
    delete[] ptr2;
  }

  // Constructor copia
  Objeto(Objeto const& obj)
    : numElems1{obj.numElems1},
      ptr1{new int[obj.numElems1]},
      numElems2{obj.numElems2},
      ptr2{new char[obj.numElems2]}
  {
    std::copy(obj.ptr1,obj.ptr1+numElems1,ptr1);
    std::copy(obj.ptr2,obj.ptr1+numElems2,ptr2);
  }

  // Constructor move
  Objeto(Objeto && obj)
    : numElems1{obj.numElems1},
      ptr1{obj.ptr1},
      numElems2{obj.numElems2},
      ptr2{obj.ptr2}
  {
    obj.numElems1 = 0;
    obj.ptr1 = nullptr;
    obj.numElems2 = 0;
    obj.ptr2 = nullptr;
  }
};

Objeto FuncionDePrueba();

Objeto a;
Objeto b(a);                 // Constructor copia;
Objeto c(std::move(a));      // Constructor move
Objeto d(FuncionDePrueba()); // Constructor move
```

Como puedes ver, invocar al constructor copia implica hacer reservas de memoria y copiar los datos de una instancia a otra... mientras que el enfoque move se dedica a mover los punteros de sitio (mucho más rápido).

Un efecto secundario de la sintaxis *move* es que el objeto original queda vacío o inservible despues de la operación. Fíjate, como se resetean los datos internos de `obj` en el *constructor move*. Es por esto que la *sintaxis move* solo tiene sentido cuando el objeto original ya no va a ser necesario.

**¿Y qué pasa con el operador de asignación?**

El operador de asignación es parecido al constructor pero con una diferencia fundamental... vamos a modificar un objeto que ya existe en vez de crear uno nuevo y esto obliga a tomar ciertas precauciones como limpiar la memoria interna antes de dedicarnos a mover punteros:

```
// Asignación tradicional
Objeto& Objeto::operator=(Objeto const& obj)
{
  delete[] ptr1;
  delete[] ptr2;

  numElems1 = obj.numElems1;
  ptr1 = new int[numElems1];
  std::copy(obj.ptr1,obj.ptr1+numElems1,ptr1);

  numElems2 = obj.numElems2;
  ptr2 = new char[numElems2];
  std::copy(obj.ptr2,obj.ptr2+numElems2,ptr2);

  return *this;
}

// Asignacion move
Objeto& Objeto::operator=(Objeto && obj)
{
  delete[] ptr1;
  delete[] ptr2;

  numElems1 = obj.numElems1;
  ptr1 = obj.ptr1;
  obj.ptr1 = nullptr;

  numElems2 = obj.numElems2;
  ptr2 = obj.ptr2;
  obj.ptr2 = nullptr;

  return *this;
}
```

**¿Cómo se invoca la *sintaxis move*?**

Esto es algo que ya se explica en el primer enlace que he puesto como referencia... recomiendo su lectura para entender el tema.

**¿La *sintaxis move* es la solución a todos mis problemas?**

Ni de broma. La *sintaxis move* ni es perfecta ni puede aplicarse siempre... si tienes objetos que no hacen uso de memoria dinámica no obtendrás ningun beneficio. Además programar esta sintaxis añade más código al proyecto... código que luego hay que mantener y probar...

**Perfect forwarding**

Este sería el último detalle que faltaría por comentar en este tema ya que sin ello la *sintaxis move* se queda coja y puede ser una fuente de errores un poco complicados de entender.

Puedes encontrar información al respecto en este [otro hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54147/cual-es-la-ventaja-de-usar-stdforward?s=1%7C37.2413)